# React native and Android 7 support with NDK restrictions

Tags: android, react-native

Native libraries must use only public API, and must not link against non-NDK platform libraries. Starting with API 24 this rule is enforced and applications are no longer able to load non-NDK platform libraries. The rule is enforced by the dynamic linker, so non-public libraries are not accessible regardless of the way code tries to load them: System.loadLibrary(...), DT_NEEDED entries, and direct calls to dlopen(...) will fail in exactly the same way.

https://android-developers.blogspot.com.by/2016/06/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.html

As I understand now React Native depends on native libraries,
any news about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That note refers only to non-public APIs. You still can load native libraries and still can use `System.loadLibrary` and `dlopen` as long as you are loading public APIs.